# Objects synchronised

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a very strange thing happening in my angular4 application that i cannot figure out for the life of me.

Essentially I am

1. Loading (@Input) in a full list of products and items into an object called products.
2. Loading (@Input) in an object called entity, that contains a property of products with a subset of the full products list i.e. only ones the user has saved into the entity.
3. Load Product Data - I push each product from this.products into productSelectionData
4. Then I run a function that loops through all the items in the productSelectionData and checks the entity object for any items that have a property called selected and change the value of selected to true

At this point everything looks good

5. Then I run a function to splice out of selectedProducts and items with a selected property of false.

This is where the problem occurs.  For some reason that is not obvious to me both the productSelectionData object and the selectedProducts object have the items with selected = false spliced out of the array.

Code Below:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProposalModel, ProductModel } from './../../../shared/models/';

@Component({
  selector: 'mj-proposal-edit',
  templateUrl: './proposal-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./proposal-edit.component.scss']
})
export class ProposalEditComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() entity: ProposalModel;
  @Input() products: ProductModel[];

  productSelectionData: any;
  selectedProducts: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    // Load all products and items
    this.loadProductData();
    this.updateProductSelectionData();
    this.filterProductsSelected();

  }

  loadProductData() {
    this.productSelectionData = [];

    this.products.forEach(product => {
      this.productSelectionData.push(
        { productTitle: product.productTitle, items: product.items })
    });
    console.log('Product Selection, after load: ', this.productSelectionData);
    debugger;
  }

  updateProductSelectionData() {
    // Update Product Selection Object with previously selected data

    // 1. Check if there is previously saved data
    if (this.entity.products !== undefined) {
      // 2. Update productSelectionData with values saved in entity object
      this.productSelectionData.forEach(product => {
        if (this.entity.products !== undefined) {
          this.entity.products.forEach(entityProduct => {
            if (product.productTitle === entityProduct.productTitle) {
              if (product.items !== undefined) {
                product.items.forEach(item => {
                  if (entityProduct.items !== undefined) {
                    entityProduct.items.forEach(entityItem => {
                      if (item.code === entityItem.code) {
                        item.selected = true;
                        item.quantity = entityItem.quantity;
                        item.discount = entityItem.discount;
                      }
                    });
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
      console.log('Product Selection, after update: ', this.productSelectionData);
      debugger;
    }
  }

  filterProductsSelected() {
    this.selectedProducts = [];
    this.productSelectionData.forEach(product => {
      this.selectedProducts.push(product)
    });
    this.selectedProducts.forEach(selectedProduct => {
      selectedProduct.items.forEach(item => {
        const itemIndex = selectedProduct.items.indexOf(item);
        if (item.selected === false) {
          selectedProduct.items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        }
        if (item.selected === undefined) {
          selectedProduct.items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        }
      });
    });
    console.log('Selected Products, after filter: ', this.selectedProducts);
    console.log('Product Selection, after filter: ', this.productSelectionData);
    debugger;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your filterProductsSelected, you're pushing the product (and its `items` array) into your `this.selectedProducts` array.

You end up with a reference to your products and their `items` in both `this.selectedProducts` and `this.productSelectionData`.

So, when you're splicing here : 
selectedProduct.items.splice(itemIndex, 1);

You are splicing in the same `items` array.

I cloned the product object and its items array and it seemed to work :

```
function filterProductsSelected() {
    selectedProducts = [];
    productSelectionData.forEach(product => {
      // cloning the product :
      var productClone = clone(product);
      // and its items :
      productClone.items = product.items.slice();
      selectedProducts.push(productClone);
    });
    selectedProducts.forEach(selectedProduct => {
      selectedProduct.items.forEach(item => {
        const itemIndex = selectedProduct.items.indexOf(item);
        if (item.selected === false) {
            console.log("not selected");
          selectedProduct.items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        }
        if (item.selected === undefined) {
            console.log("undefined selected");

        selectedProduct.items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        }
      });
    });
    console.log('Selected Products, after filter: ', selectedProducts);
    console.log('Product Selection, after filter: ', productSelectionData);
    debugger;
  }
```

The clone function code :

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you.  I have just learnt something, I had no idea that .push from one object to another creates a reference, I thought it did the complete opposite.  I will have a look at your code over the next few days.  Thanks again for the explanation and code